analytic extension $(z+4)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z-1)^n $
I wish to find the direct analytic extension of:
$ f(z) =(z+4)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z-1)^n $ for $ |z-1| <1$
And
$ g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \big(\frac{2z+2}{z+4} \big)^n  $ for $|z| < \frac {1}{2}$
They should be direct analytic continuations of each other.
I started by the first expression by using the fact that $f(z)$ is a geometric series with sum:
$$ = \frac{z+4}{(1-(z-1)} $$
$$ = \frac{z+4}{2-z} $$
for $ g(x)$ I also use the geometric series:
$$ =  \frac{1}{(1-\frac {2z+2}{z+4})} $$
But I think I am on the wrong track, or do have to use a algebraic trick?
any help appreciated....

When $|z-1|<1$,\begin{align}f(z)&=(z+4)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(z-1)^n\\&=(z+4)\frac1{1-(z-1)}\\&=\frac{4+z}{2-z}.\end{align}And, when $|z|<\frac12$,\begin{align}g(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{2z+2}{z+4}\right)^n\\&=\frac1{1-\frac{2z+2}{z+4}}\\&=\frac{4+z}{2-z}.\end{align}So, yes, at the intersection of the disk centered at $1$ with radius $1$ with the disk centered at $0$ with radius $\frac12$, $f(z)=g(z)$.

I made a calculation error in g(z), hence I got z+2 but now it is correct
